# Using sed to replace a text only in lines that matches a specific criteria

Tags: bash, sed

I want to be able to replace a line of text in a file but isn't sure how to do it with sed.

For example, if i have a properties file:

```
food.type=apple 
food.color=red
```

I want to be able to search for the category (i.e. `food.type`) and replace the text after the `=`.
i.e.

```
food.type=banana
food.color=yellow
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: I'm sorry let me add some extra clarification. What if I didn't know what text is after `food.type`. It can be anything, an 'apple', a 'banana', etc...Is it still possible to search and replace the text after the `=`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be something slightly more elegant, but you'd do it something like this:

```
sed '/^food.type/ s/=.*$/=banana/'
```

That will find a line that starts with food.type, and then replaces an equals and whatever follows it with =banana.

Comment: Sorry I added some extra clarification to my question in an edit above.

Comment: Both my answer and yi_H's should cover you. It just looks for food.type= and then anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/food\.type=.*/food.type=banana/'
```

Comment: Sorry I added some extra clarification to my question in an edit above.

Comment: Huh? This doesn't search for banana. It replaces it to banana.

Answer (score 1):

go-go back references

```
sed 's/\(food.type=\).*/\1banana/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Not just `"food.type"` now (and be more safe:)):

```
$ sed -n 's/\([a-zA-Z]*\.[a-zA-Z]*=\).*$/\1banana/' filename
```